# How do I increase Microsoft Graph Access Token expiration time?

Tags: azure, outlook, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I would like to know how to increase the access token expiration time for Microsoft Graph, any link or tips to get this done will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want to increase it? You can get new tokens with refresh tokens in a lot of scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

This API is available only in public preview (beta) here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/tokenlifetimepolicy?view=graph-rest-beta
However you should be careful about how you set this as it's a trade-off between performance and security, as explained here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes

Hope this helps,